# Angular trackBy not updating dom

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Hi y'all I can't figure this out. I'm adding elements to my array but my dom isn't updating unless I refresh the page. I'm using trackBy in a separate component and it works great but on this newer component it's not working at all.

Here's my html

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card" *ngFor="let grocery of groceryList;trackBy:trackByIdCode; index as index;">
    <div class="card-header" [id]="'grocery1'+index">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#grocery2'+index" aria-expanded="false" [aria-controls]="'grocery2'+index">
          {{grocery.recipeName}}
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div [id]="'grocery2' + index" class="collapse" [aria-labelledby]="'grocery1'+index" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        <ul class="list-group" id="filterList">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <a href="#" class="list-down-btn" data-toggle="#subgroup"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></a>
            <ul id="subgroup" class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let ingredient of grocery.ingredients">{{ingredient}}</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<mat-icon svgIcon="shopping_cart"></mat-icon>
```

Here's my component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule,ChangeDetectorRef, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import {GetRecipesService} from '../getrecipes.service';
import { MatIconRegistry } from "@angular/material/icon";
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-grocery-sidebar',
  templateUrl: './grocery-sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grocery-sidebar.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default,
  })
export class GrocerySidebarComponent implements OnInit {//

  constructor(getRecipesService: GetRecipesService,private matIconRegistry: MatIconRegistry,private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) { 
    getRecipesService.getGroceryList().subscribe(promise=>{
      this.groceryList = promise.data;
  });
    this.recipeService=getRecipesService;
    this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon("shopping_cart",this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../assets/shopping-cart-solid.svg"));
  }

  addToGroceryList(recipeName,recipeIngredients){
    this.recipeService.addToGroceryList(recipeName,recipeIngredients).subscribe(promise=>{
      console.log("addToGroeryList Promise: "+promise);
      this.refreshGroceryList();
    });

  }

  refreshGroceryList(){
    this.recipeService.getGroceryList().subscribe(promise=>{
      console.log("refreshed groceryList: "+promise.data)
      this.groceryList = promise.data;
      console.log(this.groceryList);
      this.cdr.markForCheck();
    })
  }

  deleteGroceryRecipeById(recipeId){
    this.recipeService.deleteGroceryRecipeById(recipeId).subscribe(promise=>{
      this.refreshGroceryList();
    });
  }


  public trackByIdCode(index: number, grocery: any): string {
    console.log("tracking");
    return grocery._id;
}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  recipeService;
  groceryList: object[];
  showFiller=false;
}
```

And I cant use   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush because when I do nothing displays in my dom and I can't figure out why but when I switch to   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default things display again but still don't update.

EDIT:
I've even tried a much more simple html and it still doesnt update with changes.
Here's my simple html:

```
<p *ngFor="let grocery of groceryList;trackBy:trackByCode;">{{grocery.recipeName}}</p>
```

I really really hope someone see's whats going on here because I'm at a total loss. I have no idea what else I can do

Comment: Can you create stackblitz with reproducible issue?

Answer (score 0):

it's not updating because of the trackBy - I just hit this. I'm using onPush and trackBy was causing caching issues. I haven't unravelled it totally but trackby was why I wasn't getting updates (in my case it was just an update on an attr of a single complex object in a large collection)

In your trackBy function return a string representation of the updated values and tie it to either the index or something else unique.